# How to get the unit changed automatically for different categories?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have three columns in my excel table namely *Category*, *Quantity*, *Price*. Suppose I have two categories to choose from the drop down menu : *Veggies*,
*Stationery*. What I want is the *Quantity* column to automatically change the unit according to the *Category* selected. Like if user selects *Veggies*, *Quantity* column automatically adds *"kg"* to whatever numeric value the user puts. If *Category* is Stationary, *"pcs"* is the automatic unit, and so on. How can that be done?

Also suppose if the *Quantity* input is *"2 kg"*, can it done so that when i hover my cursor to the *Price* column, a small box pops up to shown per unit price while the total price input by user is shown in the cell in *Price* column?

Comment: My reaction reading this; Excel is not a programming platform, for this kind of stuff you need a programming language, a simple choice is Python, quick to learn and follows along as an eager learner evolves.

Comment: In excel, I would split your "definition" of quantity into two separate columns, one column would be "number of units" and the second column would be "units measurement". The units would then be tied to Category with a lookup formula. Additionally, having another column to give you unit price with another lookup formula would be the way to solve your price "pop up". Otherwise, you'll need to learn VBA or any number of coding/database technologies to get what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question is resolved with `Max`'s Conditional Formatting. Excel does not let one place a formula and an entered value into the same cell, so you cannot place the logical testing you use in CF into a formula in the cell to achieve this. CF is Excel's way to let you do those two things at once for a given cell.

There ARE other ways, adding a macro to notice a cell value was entered and immediately take the value, apply the logic, and write it back with the appropriate unit measure added. Or even change that cell's regular formatting to a custom number format that leaves literally just the value there, but tacking on the unit measure's abbreviation to the displayed value. Simulating what CF does.

Another would be to add a Power Query query to the spreadsheet that every time you run it, it takes cell values that are number only values and uses your logic to add a unit measure abbreviation, then (if one is clever about how the data range is built) place the result back in the cell.

All that would be much harder than using CF, beast that CF can be. And the last one would take intervention to initiate, on the part of a user, or a VBA macro like the first one (in which case, why add the complexity of Power Query, eh?).

Alternatives like a column next to the values that carry the unit measure work too, but I'm betting your description of what you want precludes that too. So Conditional Formatting is the way to go.

As to the second, Excel just does NOT do that. You can place a Comment for a cell and something could then sort of pop up, but you cannot program the Comment's contents via formulas and such, only with VBA, but why then? Just use the VBA to generate your desire directly rather than through a second step (like I said above about a Power Query solution).

And all VBA's autorun solutions require clicking or changing a value, that kind of definite action of some small kind to initiate them automatically. I know of no `OnHover` commands. My knowledge of VBA is hardly encyclopedic though and maybe they do exist.

One thought that comes to mind is DropDowns. Create a matching column somewhere, another sheet even, just somewhere, and use that column as a source of DropDowns and create a dynamic cell address that feeds off the each cell you want unit pricing for, not trying for a whole column at a time. `CELL("address")` with nothing specified for the cell (so NOT `CELL("address,A1)`) or anything similar would work for the funky linkage, but you'd still have to click the cell you want to see it for, rather than hover.

The idea would be the cell shows the formal calculation you want it to have, and its corresponding DropDown source cell would have the price per unit quantity calculation in it. When clicking and activating the DropDown, the only "choice" shown would be that cell's result, or in other words, the chosen cell's unit price.

So you'd see the marquee result in the cell and its unit price in the only dropdown choice. Clunky, but it would put the info in front of the user when desired and not be there when not desired.

Answer (score 1):

You would do this with conditional formatting.  Conditional formatting allows you to apply a format to a cell given a formula, and one of the formatting changes you can make to a cell is the number formatting.

Select the cell or cells in the quantity column, and select conditional formatting -> manage rules, and then the bottom option in the dialog: "Use a formula to determine which cells to format."

Create a new rule, and the formula will be something like `=A1="Veggies"` and set the format to a custom number format `0" kg"` and click OK.  If you are not familiar with the format dialog, you select *custom* and then enter the format code I gave in the filed where it says "*Type*" and it will show you an example to make sure you are getting what you want.

Create another new rule, except this one is `=a1="Stationary"` and `0" pcs"` respectively.

Notes:

1. As your number of categories increases, you may wish you hadn't gone down this road, lol;
2. When you add rows, if you fill down from existing rows, the conditional formatting should follow because a conditional format is just a format.  If it doesn't you can use the format painter.